# LogLogplot of an equation

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

i need some help using LogLogPlot for graphing an equation that has various values of a parameter so that I get a set of curves on the plot. The equation is as follows:

```
(1/L^.5) + 2 Log10[(2.51/re L^.5)+.27/(d/k)]==0
```

`re` ranges from `4x10^3 to 10^7` and `d/k` takes on values of `50,200,1000,5000,100000`.

So I should have 5 curves on my plot of `Log10[L]` vs `Log10[re]`.

I'm not sure how to set this up in Mathematica.

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: Are you sure the form is right? This equation has no solution.

Comment: @Feyre `Solve` doesn't have an issue with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, it is easier to do a variable transformation.

```
logplot[var1_, var2_, func_] := Module[{f, z1, z2, l11, l12, l21, l22}, 
 f = func /. {var1 -> 10.^z1, var2 -> 10.^z2};
 l11 = Log10[4 10^3]; l12 = Log10[10^7];
 l21 = Log10[.1]; l22 = Log10[1];
 ContourPlot[f, {z1, l11, l12}, {z2, l21, l22}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Table[{x, 10^ToString[x]}, {x, 4, 7}], 
 Table[{x, 10^ToString[x]}, {x, -1, 0, .2}], None, None}]]

logplot[re, L, (1/L^.5) + 2 Log10[(2.51/re L^.5) + .27/(5000)]]
```

[image]

You can customise the `FrameTicks` or `FrameLabel` in `logplot`.